# Is it ok to change Microsoft.Phone.Controls.Toolkit's behavior and use it in the app

Tags: windows-phone-7, silverlight-toolkit

I have to change toolkit's implementations for slide transitions a little bit. Is there any legal issue in changing the toolkit's code and using it in my app.

Thanks
-Abhinav-

Comment: read the license agreement...SO is not LawyerOverflow

Comment: Also aren't you able to plug in your own transition animations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are free to modify and use the toolkit`s code. Check this : [Community Source Licensing](http://www.microsoft.com/resources/sharedsource/communitysourcelicensing.mspx)

[Microsoft Public License (Ms-PL)](http://www.microsoft.com/opensource/licenses.mspx#Ms-PL) - The Ms-PL is the least restrictive of the Microsoft source code licenses. It allows licensees to view, modify, and redistribute the source code for either commercial or non-commercial purposes. Under the Ms-PL, licensees may change the source code and share it with others. Licensees may also charge a licensing fee for their modified work if they so wish. Microsoft uses this license most commonly for its developer tools, applications, and components.